# How to share parameters around a class - C++

Tags: c++

I have a class which I intend to use for performing calculations. I declare one static object of the class elsewhere which I use to obtain results. The class has one public function apart from the constructor.

```
public:
    double getProbability(PlayerStats &p1, PlayerStats &p2, Score &score);
```

As you can see, I have three objects as input parameters. My class then has two private functions which are called from `getProbability()`. One requires `p1` and `p2`, the other requires all three of the parameters

My question is this. Is it better to pass these objects as parameters to the function or is it better to create private member variables and use these.

So for example

```
   double MyClass::getProbability(PlayerStats &p1, PlayerStats &p2, Score &score){
            otherFunction(p1,p2);
            anotherFunction(p1,p2,score);
             ....
    }
```

or

```
     double MyClass::getProbability(PlayerStats &p1, PlayerStats &p2, Score &score){
            this->p1 = p1;
            this->p2 = p2;
            this->score = score;
            otherFunction();   //use member variables in these functions
            anotherFunction();
             ....
    }
```

Comment: if you really do cash then you might have problems in case of multithreading

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by 'do cash'?

Comment: sorry, may be cashing better suits. English isnt my mother language)), its about saving previous values of p1 and p2.

Comment: By cash he means cache. As in, if you cache off the parameters as member variables, you have global state, and you will run into issues if you multi-thread this application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to pass them as parameters, as they don't really represent class state and storing them as members will probably be more performance costly than simply continuing to pass around the references.

But it doesn't really look like your class has any state at all, which leads me to believe *all* of these methods should be free-functions in a suitable namespace rather than members of a class (perhaps you come from a Java background?).

Comment: +1, may be better to do some redesign to avoid free functions?

Comment: I _do_ come from a java background :) My class does have a state (although a small one). It remembers the previous `p1` and `p2` from the previous call. If they are the same, one of the other functions does not need to be called. On that premise, I assume a class is preferred to a namespace, although I could be wrong. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I suppose I could put it into a namespace and have the previous `PlayerStats` held in a static object? would that be better

Answer (score 2):

I prefer passing the parameter to the private functions. As far as your class may be access by multiple concurrent threads, it is better to send each data to its related function.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the arguments directly to your other methods. Even if other functions used them it would be very confusing because nothing in the function signature indicates that those arguments would be kept around.

If you need some of these parameters in other functions and those parameters remain the same through several calls, you could refactor your class. It would take the ones which stay the same in the constructor and then function calls just pass in the ones which will change. It really depends on the needs of your application to determine whether this is a better approach.